# Python strange yield behavior in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, yield

This is just a demo code to understand the yield behavior in a recursive function. I expect it to return an iterable list [5,4,3] but it stops at the first iteration and only returns [5]

Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
def yield_test(input):
    if input > 3:
        yield_test(input-1)

    yield input

print(list(yield_test(5)))
```

output: [5]
Expected output:
[5, 4, 3]

Comment: yield is a keyword that is used like return, except the function will return a generator. Not the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `yield from yield_test()` and reverse the order of `yield`s in your function:

```
def yield_test(input):
    yield input

    if input > 3:
        yield from yield_test(input-1)
```